# Sites wont run on localhost following MAMP Upgrade to Ver 4.0.6

Tags: php, upgrade, mamp

I upgraded my mamp installation from 3.5 to 4.0.6 (renamed existing MAMP to MAMP-old).  Running any website on localhost will not load.  Have performed the following:

1. first migration to new MAMP I copied the db folder to the new mamp and set all the proper ports (3306 and 80).  Ran localhost/website and blank white page.
2. then reinstalled new version of MAMP and manually created needed databases and insured database user was added.  Ran localhost/website and blank white page.

If I go back to previous install of MAMP (3.5) everything works fine.  I have performed several MAMP upgrades in the past without issue.  So not sure why this upgrade is not working.

I am running on MAC Sierra.  No other 3rd part tools involved.  Working version of MAMP uses PHP 5.6.10.  New version of MAMP using PHP 5.6.27.

When localhost/website will not run, checking safari developer console shows failed to load the resource: server responded with a status of 500 (internal server error).  Verified document root is set properly.

Any suggestions for uncovering the problem would be most appreciated.

Comment: i checked the apache log and this is the error:

Comment: found this error: [Fri Dec 16 11:30:42 2016] [error] [client ::1] client denied by server configuration: /Users/Tim/Sites/.DS_Store.   Ran a cleaner to insure not DS_Store file existed.  Went to terminal as sudo and verified file does not exist.  Still cant access website locally.